# Eliminate display of Zeroes when using Group By and CASE

Tags: sql, case

I have the following code

```
SELECT Client_ID, Client_Name, 
  CASE WHEN Item_Rating = '0' THEN COUNT(Item_Rating) ELSE '' END AS 'Non Compliant', 
  CASE WHEN Item_Rating = '3' THEN COUNT(Item_Rating) ELSE '' END AS 'Partially Compliant', 
  CASE WHEN Item_Rating = '5' THEN COUNT(Item_Rating) ELSE '' END AS 'Fully Compliant', 
  CASE WHEN Item_Rating = '9' THEN COUNT(Item_Rating) ELSE '' END AS 'Incomplete', 
  COUNT(Item_Rating) AS Total
FROM     dbo.DigitalTrustFrameworkClient
GROUP BY Client_ID, Client_Name, Item_Rating
```

My challenge is that the columns are displaying a value of 0 instead of blank values ie ''.

Can anyone help me identify what I am missing? Appreciate your help.

I am expecting the colunms not applicable for each case to display blank values . I tried ''

Comment: This may depend on DBMS, but try removing ELSE from each case expression. Or perhaps change those to conditional aggregations such as `sum(case when item_rating = '0' then 1 end) as 'non_compliant'`

Comment: Adding sample data, desired output, and specify DBMS will be helpful.

Comment: A case expression returns a single scalar value of a specific type, that type can't vary; if you want a string result you'll need to cast the *count* expression.

Answer (score 0):

Your query would result in multiple rows per client. That seems a bit odd. Also, you cannot use `else ''` as that would be a string result for a column that is calculating an integer.

This works in both MySQL and SQL Server. Using conditional aggregation will result in one row per client.

```
create table table1 (
  client_id integer, 
  client_name varchar(5), 
  item_rating varchar(5)
  );
  
insert into table1 values 
(1, 'AAA', '0'), 
(1, 'AAA', '0'), 
(1, 'AAA', '5'), 
(1, 'AAA', '5'), 
(1, 'AAA', '5'), 
(1, 'AAA', '9'), 
(2, 'BBB', '0'), 
(2, 'BBB', '3'),
(2, 'BBB', '5'),
(2, 'BBB', '9');
```

```
select client_id, client_name, 
  sum(case when item_rating = '0' then 1 end) as 'non_compliant', 
  sum(case when item_rating = '3' then 1 end) as 'partially_compliant', 
  sum(case when item_rating = '5' then 1 end) as 'fully_compliant', 
  sum(case when item_rating = '9' then 1 end) as 'incomlete', 
  COUNT(Item_Rating) AS Total
FROM     table1
GROUP BY Client_ID, Client_Name;
```

| client_id | client_name | non_compliant | partially_compliant | fully_compliant | incomlete | Total |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | AAA | 2 | *null* | 3 | 1 | 6 |
| 2 | BBB | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 4 |

This returns "null" rather than 0.

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/HP-_g-ev)

Answer (score 0):

Since the `count(*)` is a numeric type then you'll need to convert it to a string using `CAST` or `CONVERT`.

```
SELECT Client_ID, Client_Name, 
  CASE WHEN Item_Rating = '0' THEN CAST(COUNT(Item_Rating) as varchar(20)) ELSE '' END AS 'Non Compliant', 
  CASE WHEN Item_Rating = '3' THEN CAST(COUNT(Item_Rating) as varchar(20)) ELSE '' END AS 'Partially Compliant', 
  CASE WHEN Item_Rating = '5' THEN CAST(COUNT(Item_Rating) as varchar(20)) ELSE '' END AS 'Fully Compliant', 
  CASE WHEN Item_Rating = '9' THEN CAST(COUNT(Item_Rating) as varchar(20)) ELSE '' END AS 'Incomplete', 
  CAST(COUNT(Item_Rating) as varchar(20)) AS Total
FROM     dbo.DigitalTrustFrameworkClient
GROUP BY Client_ID, Client_Name, Item_Rating
```